# Arithmetic of a combinations formula

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I am trying to study, and I'm not quite sure how:

$$ \binom{5}{3} \cdot \binom{7}{3} = 350 $$

From my understanding the formula is

$$ \binom{n}{r} = \frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!} $$

Therefore:

$$ \binom{5}{3} = \frac{5!}{3!(5-3)!} = 10 $$

and

$$ \binom{7}{3} = \frac{7!}{3!(7-3)!} = 35 $$

Please help me understand, thank you.

Answer: $ 10\cdot 35 = 350$.

Comment: I would like to edit your Question to use math symbols, but I need your help to make sure I'm properly representing what you mean.  In the second line, does "and" mean addition or multiplication?

Comment: @hardmath: You could try both possibilities and see which one gives the right answer (multiplication does). Of course this is not something _you_ should have to do though.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen: Heh, yes, I often have the urge to edit Questions so that they give right Answers.  But I'm resisting this!

Comment: sorry guys go for it!
it means multiplication hardmath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your calculation of ${7 \choose 3}$. You made a typo in the denominator and the result is not $24$, but $35$.

Answer (score 0):

$ {7 \choose 3} $ should be $\frac{7!}{3!\cdot 4!}$ , which is 35.

Answer (score 0):

Note that; $$7C3=\frac{7!}{3!(7-3)!}=35$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\binom53=\frac{5!}{3!(5-3)!}=\frac{5!}{3!2!}=\frac{1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot4\cdot5}{1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot1\cdot2}=\frac{4\cdot5}{1\cdot2}=\frac{20}2=10$$
$$\binom73=\frac{7!}{3!(7-3)!}=\frac{7!}{3!4!}=\frac{7!}{4!3!}=\frac{1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot4\cdot5\cdot6\cdot7}{1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot4\cdot1\cdot2\cdot3}=\frac{5\cdot6\cdot7}{1\cdot2\cdot3}=\frac{5\cdot6\cdot7}6=5\cdot7=35$$
$$\binom53\binom73=10\cdot35=350$$